# Intermediate variables in a SAS macro

Tags: sas, sas-macro

Here's my macro, below. The variables var1, var2, var3, VR, and maxwt are not input to the macro, and are not on a file. They are intermediate results which are calculated inside the macro. When I execute in in SAS 9.3, I get a message like this:

```
1      var1 = &dcount1 * (&spop1/&refpr1)**2;
       ----
       180

ERROR 180-322: Statement is not valid or it is used out of proper order.
```

Macro:

```
%macro confi (aart,dcount1,dcount2,dcount3,spop1,spop2,spop3,refpr1=0.53468238,refpr2=0.30153350,refpr3=0.16378412);
    var1 = &dcount1 * (&spop1/&refpr1)**2;
    var2 = &dcount1 * (&spop2/&refpr2)**2;
    var3 = &dcount3 * (&spop1/&refpr3)**2;

    VR = var1+var2+var3;

    maxwt = max(&refpr1 &refpr2 &refpr3);

    CI_low = (VR/ 2*&aart)) * cinv(0.025,2*(&aart**2)/VR);
    CI_high = (( VR + maxwt**2) / (2*(&aart+maxwt)))* cinv(0.975, 2*(&aart+maxwt)**2/(VR + maxwt**2));

    %put &aart CI_low CI_high;

%mend confi;

%confi (aart=1000, dcount1=20, dcount2=70, dcount3= 10. spop1=3000, spop2=3000, spop3=200);
```

Answer (score 1):

That macro would have to be executed inside of a data step.  Those are data step variables and statements and can't be executed in open code.

You also can't use `%put` for that purpose - you need to use `put`.

Answer (score 1):

1. You are missing the datastep to calculate all your non-macro variables.
2. When you call a MACRO to execute, it is a BEST PRACTICE not to put ; at the end of the line.
3. On the CI_LOW arithmetic operation you have mismatch parenthesis.
4. When you call the macro %confi, you are assigning dcount3 variable value wrong, you need a comma, not a dot.
5. When you declare a Macro, you don't assign values there, only declare variables.
6. On the Max Function, the variables need to be separated by commas.

Try this:

```
Options Macrogen Symbolgen;
%macro confi (aart,dcount1,dcount2,dcount3,spop1,spop2,spop3,refpr1,refpr2,refpr3); 

data _null_;
var1 = &dcount1 * (&spop1/&refpr1)**2; 
var2 = &dcount1 * (&spop2/&refpr2)**2; 
var3 = &dcount3 * (&spop1/&refpr3)**2;
VR = var1+var2+var3;

maxwt = max(&refpr1, &refpr2, &refpr3);


CI_low = (VR/ 2*&aart) * cinv(0.025,2*(&aart**2)/VR);
CI_high = (( VR + maxwt**2) / (2*(&aart+maxwt)))* cinv(0.975, 2*(&aart+maxwt)**2/(VR + maxwt**2));

put 'low =' CI_low;
put 'high = ' CI_high;

run;

%put &aart;

%mend confi;

%confi (aart=1000, dcount1=20, dcount2=70, dcount3= 10, spop1=3000, spop2=3000, spop3=200, refpr1=0.53468238, refpr2=0.30153350, refpr3=0.16378412)
```

Comment: Putting a `;` at the end of the line is often necessary to get the syntax highlighter to work properly, unfortunately.    For 5., that's incorrect; you can assign default values (and it sounds like that's desired here).  For 6., either commas or include the `of` keyword.

Comment: For 5, I agree that you can declare default values when you declare a Macro.  That would raise a question, what is the point of a macro then?.  For ; after calling a MACRO, I am not sure what you mean by "is often necessary to get the syntax highlighter to work properly".  In fact, the official documentation does not even mention the need of a ; in other words, the compiler ignores the ;.

Comment: Default values make sense when you sometimes want a value populated and sometimes don't.  I use them all the time.  For the `;` bit, the syntax highlighter is the part of the enhanced editor or enterprise guide that turns keywords different colors; missing the `;` after a macro call is not necessary for the program to work, but it will sometimes cause the highlighter to be confused, so the next statement may not be properly highlighted.  (Obviously, there are some cases where the `;` is a problem, and in those cases it must be left out.)